# 1980's Quest movie with arm amputation by sword

Tags: story-identification

My favorite cult classic movie memory is from the 1980's. It was one of those B-movies they show on HBO or Cinemax late at night. Its a Quest movie. Swords and Sorcery. Possibly apocalyptic scenario. Lots of scantily clad babes. Lots of macho dudes. They assembled a team to go on a quest for some reason. Dont remember what.

The best scene is when they try to cross a bridge. There is a guy standing there who won't let them pass. So one of our heroes takes his sword and chops the guys arm off. While we're distracted, the arm becomes a clone of the man guarding the bridge. Awesome movie. Probably cheeseball. Might be British but its **def not Monty Python.**

Comment: ['tis but a scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdSLP-qz_fw)

Comment: Are you sure they weren't hiding behind the chainsaws?

Answer (score 4):

### [*She*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090009/)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_(1982_film)), this film is post-apocalyptic, occurring “23 years after an event called ‘The Cancellation.’”

An IMDB [review](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090009/reviews) mentions the bridge guard:

> Mix together sword-and-sorcery and post-apocalyptic elements, add a
>   dose of political allegory (note the Communist and Nazi symbols), a
>   contemporary music score and some surreal moments that seem to have
>   come straight out of Monty Python (**a bridge guard who multiplies every
>   time you chop off one of his limbs**) and you have this bizarre film
>   that is neither a straight adventure nor exactly a spoof.

And of course, the lightly-dressed women:

> It suffers from an overly episodic structure, but it benefits from
>   Sandahl Bergman and Quin Kessler as the two muscular, beautiful Amazon
>   warriors who are as proficient with a sword as with any other weapon.